# Sufficient Condition for compact embedding in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Have the following exercise and do not even know where to start. Any hints, links, or even names of what I am looking for would be extremely helpful.

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ a normed space continuously embedded in $X$. Let the sequence $(h_n)$ converge to $0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then if there exist $C>0$, a sequence $(X_n)$ of finite-dimensional subspaces of $X$, and a sequence $(I_n)$ of continuous and linear operators $I_n \in L(Y,X_n)$ such that
$$ \|u-I_nu \|_X \leq C h_n \| u \|_Y \quad \forall u \in Y$$
then $Y$ is compactly embedded in $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to show that the inclusion $i:Y\to X$ is compact as operator. By assumption, we can look at the operators $I_n$ as operators from $Y$ to $X$ of finite rank, that is operators such that the image of $I_n$ is finite dimensional for all $n$. Now there is a result that says that a limit of a sequence of finite rank operators is compact (see *Brezis - Functional Analysis* for example). And we actually have that $i$ is limit of the sequence of $I_n$, in fact using our hypotheses we have that:

$$\|i-T_n\|_{L(Y,X)}=\sup_{u\in Y,\|u\|=1} \|u-I_n(u)\|_X\le \sup_{u\in Y,\|u\|=1} Ch_n\|u\|_Y=Ch_n\to0\quad n\to\infty.$$

Comment: Exactly what I needed. If anyone else encounters this question, see beginning of Chapter 6 of that book.